# Error when attempting to combine limit with paginate

Tags: laravel-lighthouse

When performing the GraphQL query below, lighthouse throws the following error:

> Nuwave\Lighthouse\Pagination\PaginatorField::dataResolver():
> Argument #1 ($root) must be of type
> Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator, array given,
> called in
> /code/vendor/nuwave/lighthouse/src/Schema/Directives/FieldDirective.php
> on line 51

This only seems to happen when I combine `limit` and `paginate`. If I remove the `limit: 1` from my query, or replace `@paginate` in my schema with `@all`, the request completes succesfully.

Why are these options seemingly incompatible?

Using lighthouse 5.48 and laravel 9.11

My query:

```
query getLastPlayed{
  requests(
    limit: 1
  ) {
    paginatorInfo{
      total
      hasMorePages
    }
    data {
      id
      media {
        title
        duration
      }
      requested_at
    }
  }
}
```

My schema:

```
type Request {
    id: ID!
    media: Media! @belongsTo
    requested_by: User @hasOne
    requested_at: DateTime!
    played_at: DateTime
}

type Query {
    requests(
            limit: Int @limit
        ): [Request!]! @paginate(defaultCount: 10)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use limit. the paginate directive already injects an argument called "first" into your query.

`users(first: 10)` will return only 10 users.